# Submit button style in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, submit

I have a question to the submit- button behavior of internet explorer. If I load the page everything is fine - the submit button looks as it should.

[Inactive state http://img58.imageshack.us/img58/7214/inactiveci9.jpg](http://img58.imageshack.us/img58/7214/inactiveci9.jpg)

But if I click inside the FORM, the submit button gets some additional style which I don't like (see image for more information).

[image: Active state]

How can I disable this behavior. I'm using IE7 under Vista.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS:

```
input:focus, 
input:active, 
input:hover 
{ 
   outline: none; 
   border: 1px solid; 
}
```

No guarantees, but that is **supposed** to stop IE being stupid.

You should extend the above style a little, for instance, change background color or border color to give an alternative change indicating focus.

( press tab, you'll see it move ;) , the additional style is an indicator showing what action will be performed upon pressing ENTER )

Comment: Why is IE being stupid? It's just following standard Windows UI conventions.

Comment: @John, yay, but which comes first, W3C, or windows, ?

Comment: @Kent - Where do the W3C specify what submit buttons should look like?

Answer (score 4):

This indicates that button is focused. It's needed for keyboard navigation. You should't remove it.

If you however value looks of your design over usability and accesibility, then try [hideFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533783.aspx) property (at least it's not as harmful as `blur()`).

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same behaviour in IE. As far as I know, the only way to prevent that behaviour is to set the button border property to none - not ideal as that obviously effects the style of your button.

Answer (score 1):

This is just standard Windows behaviour where the default button—i.e. the button that's clicked if you press Enter—gets a slightly thicker border.